# c++0x merging tuples

Tags: c++11, tuples

I am trying to come up with a generic template for merging a list of tuples or types in one tuple. I am getting an error when compiling.

```
template<typename... Types>
struct merge_tuples{ typedef std::tuple<> type;};

template<typename Type>
struct merge_tuples<Type> {
  typedef std::tuple<Type> type;
};

template<typename...Types>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types...> type;
};

template<typename...Types1,typename...Types2>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...>,std::tuple<Types2...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types1...,Types2...> type;
};

template<typename...Types1,typename...Types2,typename...Rest>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...>,std::tuple<Types2...>,Rest...> {
  typedef decltype(merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...,Types2...>,decltype(merge_tuples<Rest...>::type)>::type) type;
};

template<typename...Types1,typename Type>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...>,Type> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types1...,Type> type;
};
typedef std::tuple<int,double> int_double;
typedef merge_tuples<int_double,int_double,int_double>::type megred;
```

The error I am getting is the following

```
lalr_grammar.cpp:152:97: error: unexpected type name 'type': expected expression
  typedef decltype(merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...,Types2...>,decltype(merge_tuples<Rest...>::type)>::type) type;
                                                                                                ^
lalr_grammar.cpp:420:11: note: in instantiation of template class 'merge_tuples<std::__1::tuple<int, double>, std::__1::tuple<int, double>, std::__1::tuple<int, double> >' requested here
  typedef merge_tuples<int_double,int_double,int_double>::type megred;
```

Comment: What is the error? Why would you make it harder for us by not giving it when you want an answer?

Comment: Does `std::tuple_cat` already do what you're trying to do? (I'm not sure what `merge_tuples` actually does).

Comment: merge_tuples will make a new tuple from a list of tuples or types 

tuple_cat did not seem to do what I wanted I will look into it agian

Comment: Liberally sprinkle `typename` around until it compiles. :-)

Comment: Howard Hinnant it worked thanks for the advice I will post the answer after I am allowed to since I am new here

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice Howard Hinnant
I took your advice and made some additional changes and it works

```
template<typename... Types>
struct merge_tuples{
  typedef std::tuple<Types...> type;
};

template<>
struct merge_tuples<> {
  typedef std::tuple< > type;
};

template<typename Type>
struct merge_tuples<Type> {
  typedef std::tuple<Type> type;
};

template<typename...Types>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types...> type;
};

template<typename...Types1,typename...Types2>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...>,std::tuple<Types2...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types1...,Types2...> type;
};

template<typename Type1,typename Type2>
struct merge_tuples<Type1,Type2> {
  typedef std::tuple<Type1,Type2> type;
};

template<typename Type,typename... Types>
struct merge_tuples<Type,std::tuple<Types...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<Type,Types...> type;
};

template<typename... Types,typename Type>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types...>,Type> {
  typedef std::tuple<Types...,Type> type;
};

template<typename...Types,typename Type,typename... Rest>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types...>,Type,Rest...> {
  typedef typename merge_tuples<Rest...>::type temp;
  typedef typename merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types...,Type>,temp>::type type;
};

template<typename Type,typename... Types,typename... Rest>
struct merge_tuples<Type,std::tuple<Types...>,Rest...> {
  typedef typename merge_tuples<Rest...>::type temp;
  typedef typename merge_tuples<std::tuple<Type,Types...>,temp>::type type;
};

template<typename...Types1,typename... Types2,typename... Rest>
struct merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...>,std::tuple<Types2...>,Rest...> {
  typedef typename merge_tuples<Rest...>::type temp;
  typedef typename merge_tuples<std::tuple<Types1...,Types2...>,temp>::type type;
};

template<typename Type1,typename Type2,typename... Rest>
struct merge_tuples<Type1,Type2,Rest...> {
  typedef typename merge_tuples<Rest...>::type temp;
  typedef typename merge_tuples<std::tuple<Type1,Type2>,temp>::type type;
};
```